# Converting a set to a list in Isabelle

Tags: isabelle

How can I convert a set to a list in Isabelle?

I am interested in a function definition, with the signature:

```
"'a set => 'a list"
```

How can I define this?

Comment: In general this will only work for finite sets (or by returning a nonsense result for infinite ones). When you say "function definition" do you mean some arbitrary function (definable in Isabelle/HOL) or something that is also executable as functional code?

Comment: For anyone finding this thread, let me point out that https://www.isa-afp.org/browser_info/current/AFP/Comparison_Sort_Lower_Bound/Linorder_Relations.html exists. Thank you goes out to the author of that theory :). It is part of the Archive For Formal Proofs (https://www.isa-afp.org/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By searching for `"'a set" "'a list"` in the *Find Constants* tab of Isabelle/jEdit's *Query* panel I stumbled upon

```
sorted_list_of_set :: "'a set ⇒ 'a list"
```

from theory `List`. However, this constant requires `'a` to be in class `linorder`, i.e., it applies only to sets over linearly ordered elements. Moreover, as mentioned in my comment, it only works for finite sets. There is also a warning directly above the definition of `sorted_list_of_set` which I repeat here for completeness:

> This function maps (finite) linearly ordered sets to sorted
>   lists. Warning: in most cases it is not a good idea to convert from
>   sets to lists but one should convert in the other direction (via
>   @{const set}).

Answer (score 3):

You can start with

```
definition set_to_list :: "'a set ⇒ 'a list"
  where "set_to_list s = (SOME l. set l = s)"
```

and then prove

```
lemma  set_set_to_list:
   "finite s ⟹ set (set_to_list s) = s"
unfolding set_to_list_def by (metis (mono_tags) finite_list some_eq_ex)
```